# How to install the drivers for my samsung ml-1670?

Tags: software-installation

I have the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version and I downloaded the .tar.gz file from the samsung website, I already extracted it content, but I don't know what to do now to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you don't have to install drivers from Samsung, as Linux supports many printers out of the box.

I have similar one here, I just plugged it into power source and into PC, turned it on and went to `Print settings`. When I clicked `Add printer` it was already there.

So, it should be very simple. It is Linux after all, not M$ :)

Comment: Yeah I restart the computer and it works then xD thanks dude. i'm still learning the magic of linux :'D